How did I get started with classification in python?
Hello I am confused on what it is asking.Question
I got started: code begin------------
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal    

class ClusterClassifier:
    def __init__(self, threshold=0.9):
        self.threshold = threshold
        self.mean = None
        self.covariance = None

    def train(self, data):
        self.mean = np.mean(data, axis=0)
        self.covariance = np.cov(data, rowvar=False)

code work in progress-----
Something out an output is what I assume the question is asking.
